# Why didn't I get all the files when I git cloned this directory?

Tags: git, open-source, github

I did

```
git clone https://github.com/niltsh/MPlayerX
```

And it seemed to be downloading everything. But when it finished I went into the folder, and I found a lot of things were missing.

Why didn't it get everything? Is it because those folders are from other projects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The submodules are missing because you didn't download them.  The following commands should get them.

```
$ git submodule init
$ git submodule update
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it in one step with:

```
$ git clone --recursive RepoURLHere
```

:)